# Is it possible to edit the JWT token?

Tags: jwt, token, bearer-token

Is it possible to edit the JWT token and re-use it?

I was trying to edit a JWT Token and re-use it, i decoded the JWT from https://www.jsonwebtoken.io the Token was using a RS256 algorithm and in the Signing key section it was saying that, Invalid - Token Signature has failed.

So after editing the user id from the Token and using the edited token in request i got an error that the Token was not accepted.

P.S: The token get shrunk after editing the id.

Comment: after changing the payload, the signature doesn't match anymore and verification fails. That's for what you have a signature! I'll mark this question as a duplicate of an similar one. Please read that question and the answer and you'll understand.